# git clone is aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side even though memory settings are done properly

Tags: git, github

git clone is aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side 
even though memory settings are done properly

I would **able to fetch and push my codes** to same repo. when I try to clone in another machine it says error.

**Here is .gitconfig settings**

```
[pack]
    windowMemory = 1000m
    SizeLimit = 1000m
    threads = 1
    window = 0
```

**Error:**

```
   Cloning into 'auto_shop'...
    stdin: is not a tty
    remote: Counting objects: 3043, done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2872/2872), done.
    error: pack-objects died of signal 94.62 MiB | 89.00 KiB/s
    error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
    fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
    fratal: early EOF:  31% (966/3043), 5.68 MiB | 223.00 KiB/s
    emote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
    fatal: index-pack failed
```

Also, `git fsck` does not give any errors.

```
# git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (2218/2218), done.
dangling commit 7ae478bea3aa6c42cc8fe865c9fc26b35ea9e15d
dangling commit a657b57b65f63f4ffea1c25c77ff62c94471d41a
dangling commit 3c9ef0ff7818812f506fa1d18ef4af4a90a4938d
```

Please help me how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Uhhh, have you considered there's a possible corruption on the remote side?

Comment: I would able to fetch and push my codes to same repo. when i try to clone in another machine it says error.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It worked , I set the same config in remote side as well. it worked now..

```
git config --global pack.windowMemory "100m"
git config --global pack.SizeLimit "100m" 
git config --global pack.threads "1"
git config --global pack.window "0"
```

Comment: In the event this answer does not work, is there anything else one could try?

Comment: This answer didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 17):

I met the same problem. After trying all solutions, it still exists. After compare the config to another repository, I found this config works:

```
git config core.bigfilethreshold 200K
```

I think it is because there is a large sql backup file `backup.sql(size: 305M)`, git tryied to analysis it as a text file and see the difference.
After using `git config core.bigfilethreshold 200K` git will not store it deflated nor trying to compress it.

So if configurations like `pack.windowMemory, pack.SizeLimit` didn't work for you, try using
`git config core.bigfilethreshold 200K`.

Comment: Just to clarify this a little more: the setting needs to be applied to the remote repository itself – means server-side.